# static_assert with nonconstexpr objects in hana's tutorial

Tags: c++, constexpr, static-assert

Reading the [hana's tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html#tutorial-quickstart), I wonder how can that `static_assert` work as expected:

```
template <typename Any>
auto switch_(Any& a) {
  return [&a](auto ...cases_) {
    auto cases = hana::make_tuple(cases_...);

    auto default_ = hana::find_if(cases, [](auto const& c) {
      return hana::first(c) == hana::type_c<default_t>;
    });

    static_assert(default_ != hana::nothing,
      "switch is missing a default_ case");

    // ...
  };
}
```

The documentation explicitly states that `default_` is not a `constexpr` object, so, even if the overload of `operator!=` for those types is a `constexpr` function, the expression `default_ != hana::nothing` cannot be a constant expression since one of its arguments isn't.

The tutorial says:

> Notice how we can use static_assert on the result of the comparison
>   with nothing, even though `default_` is a non-constexpr object? Boldly,
>   Hana makes sure that no information that's known at compile-time is
>   lost to the runtime, which is clearly the case of the presence of a
>   `default_` case.

What does the tutorial refer to with that paragraph, or how does that expression work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You misunderstand what `constexpr` requires.  You can pass non-`constexpr` args to a `constexpr` function, and the result *can* be `constexpr`.

A toy example:

```
struct foo {
  int x;
  foo(int in):x(in){}
  friend constexpr bool operator==(foo const&, foo const&) { return true; }
};
```

then

```
foo a{1}, b{2};
static_assert( a==b, "works" );
```

is perfectly valid.

Heck, I could allocate those `foo` on the heap, and `==` would still evaluate as a `constexpr` expression.

`default_` is not `constexpr`, but comparing it with `nothing` can be done using only the *type* information of `default_`, which is available at compile time.  Nothing compares equal to `hana::nothing` but (another instance of) nothing.

```
struct toy_nothing_t {
  friend constexpr bool operator==(toy_nothing_t const&, toy_nothing_t const&) {
    return true;
  }
  template<class T>
  friend constexpr bool operator==(T const&, toy_nothing_t const&) {
    return false;
  }
  template<class T>
  friend constexpr bool operator==(toy_nothing_t const&, T const&) {
    return false;
  }
};
```

this `toy_nothing_t` has similar properties.